# How do I output 1 field value from a related based on the condition that there is 1 record with that value

Tags: apex, visualforce, conditional

How do I output 1 field value from a relatedlist based on the condition that there is 1 record with that value. I tried the following but I get an syntax error see:

```
<apex:repeat var="ex" value="{!Opportunity.OpportunityLineItems}">
IF(ex.Product2=='20ft',<apex:variable var="a" value="{!ex.Product2}" />,'')
</apex:repeat>
<apex:outputText> {!IF({!a}=='20ft',{!a},'')} </apex:outputText>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display it while iterating itself. Use rendered attribute.

```
<apex:repeat var="ex" value="{!Opportunity.OpportunityLineItems}">
   <apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(ex.Product2=='20ft',true,false)}">
     {!ex.Product2}
   </apex:outputText>
</apex:repeat>
```

For finding the last item after full iteration;

```
<apex:variable var="outputProd2" value=""/>
<apex:repeat var="ex" value="{!Opportunity.OpportunityLineItems}">
   <apex:variable var="outputProd2" value="{!IF(ex.Product2=='20ft',ex.Product2,outputProd2)}"/>
</apex:repeat>
<apex:outputText> {!outputProd2} </apex:outputText>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since this is within the repeat, if there are more records with true I will get several outputs. In my case I only want to show that 1 type of product is used despite of have several records with the same product. for example record(1,2,1,1,1,2,2,3,5,6,7,10,10,10,1,1) IF repeat record.field==1 Output 1,IF repeat record.field==10 Output 10

Comment: @Jenssen I have added a second part to my answer. Check if this helps. I have not compiled the code. Please let me know if you get any compilation error.

Comment: thanks for helping but I get the error: Error: Unknown property 'OpportunityStandardController.outputProd2'

Comment: I Got this working the following way Thanks!, If jou edit your answer I will accept the solution: '
 <apex:repeat value="{!Opportunity.OpportunityLineItems}" var="ex">
                     <apex:variable value="" var="outputProd2"/> 
                     <apex:variable var="outputProd2" value="{!IF(ex.Product2.Name=='20ft',ex.Product2.Name,outputProd2)}"/>
              </apex:repeat>
<apex:outputText> {!outputProd2} </apex:outputText>'

Comment: I guess setting value as {!null} in the first line was the problem. I have removed it. But in the code in above comment you have added <apex:variable value="" var="outputProd2"/> inside the repeat. This will erase the field value each time. Keep this above the <apex:repeat/>

Comment: Your right just figured that out, solution:'<apex:variable value="null" var="outputProd2"/>
              <apex:repeat value="{!Opportunity.OpportunityLineItems}" var="ex">
              <apex:variable var="outputProd2" value="{!IF(ex.Product2.Name=='40ft',ex.Product2.Name,'')}"/>
              </apex:repeat><apex:outputtext value="{!IF(outputProd2 =='40ft','/'+outputProd2, '')}"/>'

Comment: I think code in my answer will work without any change. And code in the above comment, you do not have to set value="null" in the firstline. just set value="". And line <apex:variable var="outputProd2" value="{!IF(ex.Product2.Name=='40ft',ex.Product2.Name,'')}"/‌​> should be <apex:variable var="outputProd2" value="{!IF(ex.Product2.Name=='40ft',ex.Product2.Name,outputProd2)}"/‌​>.